# iccube - Gantt Amchart - how to switch scrollbar Axe?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, iccube-reporting

Looking at the AMChart demo [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/), I see the scrollbar is on top of the chart.
[image]

It is made visible using the folowing code

```
  "valueScrollbar": {
    "autoGridCount": true
  },
```

In IcCube reporting, When I create a gantt and select "Scrollbar Enabled", the scroll appears on the right of the chart, on the other Axis.

[image]

How can I switch this ? I did not find the right option ? is it available ?

**UPDATE :**

I got it working putting the following code

```
/**
 * Return patched 
 * options object.
 */
function(context, options) {
    debugger
    options.dataRenderOptions.valueScrollbar = Object;
 options.dataRenderOptions.valueScrollbar.autoGridCount=false;
 return options;
}
```

in the `Before Render` JS code of the widget.

But still would be better if iCcube could integrate this internally.

Comment: The scrollbar they're enabling with that option is the `chartScrollbar`, not the `valueScrollbar`. Not sure where the `valueScrollbar` is set in the iccube platform or if they even tied that functionality into their system.

Comment: Thanks to @xorspark,  I succeeded adding this `valueScrollbar` directly in the code behind the icCube widget!  But now, everytime I change an option using iccube IDE, it is lost. IcCube guys, can you implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IcCube guys included this new functionality in their 6.8.6 release. Thanks